# how to pass a hash along with other arguments to a subroutine in perl?

Tags: perl, hash, subroutine

my code:

```
$self->commitToPerforce($network_name[0], {"size_of_table=>$row->{numRecords}"});

sub commitToPerforce {
    my $self = shift;
    my $network = shift;
    my %metadata = shift;

    open my $FH, ">$local_metadata_file" || die "Could not open file $local_metadata_file";
    print $FH Dumper(%metadata);
    close $FH;
}
```

problem is, this is what's getting into the file:

```
$VAR1 = 'HASH(0x320adf0)';
$VAR2 = undef;
```

not what I'm looking for.

Also tried this:

```
print $FH Dumper(\%metadata);
```

which just gives me this:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'HASH(0x223cea0)' => undef
    };
```

I want the *contents* of the hash. Not the reference to the hash.

getting closer now:

```
my $hash = {"size_of_table=>$row->{numRecords}"};
$self->commitToPerforce($network_name[0], $hash);

   open( my $FH, ">", $local_metadata_file ) || die "Could not open file $local_metadata_file";
print $FH Dumper($metadata);
close $FH;
```

results in:

```
 $VAR1 = {
      'size_of_table=>0' => undef
    };
```

what's with the 'undef'??

oh. i see it now. my hash should not be a single string.

and just because there's no where else for me to gripe: why is it a good idea to spend so much time thinking about my data structures in this way?

Comment: *"why is it a good idea to spend so much time thinking about my data structures in this way?"* It's an investment. Like any part of any programming language, practising it will help you to understand it better, and you will soon be able to write correct code without guesswork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some comments on your code

- I hope the *call* to `commit_to_perforce` is in a different file from the method definition?
- It is often much clearer to define a hash parameter separately and then pass a reference to it, rather than passing an anonymous hash directly in the parameter list
- Within a method, it is usually best to `shift` the vlaue of `$self` off the parameter list, and then do a list assignment for the rest of the parameters
- You should use the three-parameter form of `open`, and either check that it succeeded with a `die` string that includes `$!` to give the *reason* for the failure, or just `use autodie`.

  Because of the precedence of the `||` operator, your code checks the truth of the string `">$local_metadata_file"` instead of the return value from `open`. You can either use the low-precedence `or` operator instead or put parentheses around the parameters to `open`
- It is common practice to reserve upper case letters for global identifiers, such as the package `Dumper`. Local variables should normally be named using lower-case letters, numbers, and underscore

Taking all of that into account, here's how your code should look

```
my %meta = (
  size_of_table => $row->{numRecords},
);

$self->commit_to_perforce($network_name[0], \%meta);
```

```
sub commit_to_perforce {
  my $self = shift;
  my ($network, $metadata) = @_;

  open my $fh, '>', $local_metadata_file
      or die "Could not open file '$local_metadata_file' for output: $!";
  print $fh Dumper $metadata;
  close $fh;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: @Ramy: Most of your problem is explained in [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) in the section on *"List value constructors"*. The rest, as Andy says, is in [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). Please read them. If you learn their wisdom and practice the examples then it will become part of you before long at all

Answer (score 1):

First problem: You are passing in a hash reference to the function (which is the right way to do it), but you're treating is as a hash inside the function.

Second problem: You also apparently don't have `use warnings` turned on because you should have received this warning:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at programname.pl line X
```

So, first thing, go put `use warnings;` at the top of your program.

Third problem: You have a bug with your `open` because it will never fail, due to operator precedence.  This statement:

```
open my $FH, ">$local_metadata_file" || die "Could not open file $local_metadata_file";
```

is effectively:

```
open my $FH, (">$local_metadata_file" || die "Could not open file $local_metadata_file");
```

So the `">$local_metadata_file"` will always be true, and always evaluate to that string, and then nothing checks the return code of `open`.  While you're at it, change to modern 3-argument `open`.  Change to either

```
open my $FH, ">", $local_metadata_file or die "Could not open file $local_metadata_file";
```

or

```
open( my $FH, ">", $local_metadata_file" ) || die "Could not open file $local_metadata_file";
```

Roll it all up into this function:

```
sub commitToPerforce {
    my $self = shift;
    my $network = shift;
    my $metadata = shift; # Hash reference, not a hash.

    open my $FH, ">", $local_metadata_file or die "Could not open file $local_metadata_file";
    print $FH Dumper(%{$metadata});
    close $FH;
}
```

You can also pass a hashreference to `Dumper` and it will treat it as a hash rather than just a flattened list of key/value pairs, which is what happens when you pass in a hash.

```
    print $FH Dumper($metadata);
```

Learn about references.  They are crucial to using Perl effectively.  Run `perldoc perlreftut` to read the tutorial that comes with Perl.

EDIT

I just noticed the other thing you're doing wrong.  This line

```
{"size_of_table=>$row->{numRecords}"};
```

is building a one-element hash with a string for a key, and no value.  What you really want is

```
{ size_of_table => $row->{numRecords} };
```

Now you have a one-element hash that has a single key `size_of_table` that refers to the numeric value that lives in `$row->{numRecords}`, whatever that may be.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation to perlreftut. but i don't think this actually answers my question.

Comment: `{"size_of_table=>$row->{numRecords}"}` is not a hash.  It is a reference to a hash.  The `{}` is an anonymous hash constructor.  Seriously: Read `perlreftut`.

Comment: @Ramy: You said yourself in your question: `{"size_of_table=>$row->{numRecords}"}` creates a hash containing just a single string. You want `{ size_of_table => $row->{numRecords} }`

Comment: yes. deleted that comment. but i still don't get the warning.